# Why there is no local variable capture? C# closure bahavior

Tags: c#

I wrote this convert code in a IMultiValueConverter

```
public object Convert(object[] values ...)
{
   return new Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand<object>(
                delegate
                {
                    foreach (ICommand cmd in values)
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(null);
                    }
                });
}
```

values parameters were two command objects, but when the callback executes (WPF mulibinding) values array includes only null values. Why? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: `Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand<object>` - I'm so glad I don't have to write .NET code...

Comment: You are aware of the fact that he just didn't use the using directive to show what class he is talking about? Normally, it would just be `return new DelegateCommand [...]`.

Comment: Did you check and see if you are binding the values properly? The Code could be helpful

Answer (score 6):

Nothing in your method is changing the value of `values`, so in this case it's *as if* the variable `values` was being captured directly. The normal caveats about the *variable* being captured aren't applicable - unless, of course, you've got more code in the method which you haven't shown us...

Note that if something else changes the values *within the array* after the method has returned but before the delegate executes, those changes will still be seen. If you don't want that, you should clone the array yourself:

```
public object Convert(object[] values)
{
   object[] copy = (object[]) values.Clone();
   return new DelegateCommand<object>(
                delegate
                {
                    foreach (ICommand cmd in copy)
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(null);
                    }
                });
}
```

It's not really clear from your question what's happening, but hopefully that will help...

Comment: Jon, great! It works. Thank you for all your skilled answers.

Comment: Mental compiler error: "local variable `copy` assigned and never read"